# Vamos criar um array de tags sobre arrays?

Tags: debate, tags

Não vou dizer que todas estão erradas, provavelmente quase todas estão certas. A *tag* mãe é claramente [array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array), tem outras que usam o termo e não sei se não é a mesma coisa, por exemplo [jsonarray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonarray), que não sei nem se deveria ter essa grafia, se for válida.

Tem caso mais complicado, [arraylist](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arraylist) é um *array*, uma lista ou nenhum dos dois? Poderia fundir com [array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) ou com [lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lista), qual?

Quais devem morrer?

Comment: A tag arraylist é relacionada com o Java, é um tipo de dados que tem comportamento parecido com array, mas não é array. Mas também não me parece ser List.

Comment: È uma lista que internamente tem um array.

Comment: Então é um ArrayList :D

Comment: Não dá para fundir [tag:array] com [tag:lista] em linguagens que suportam `array push` lista e array são bem similares, mas em linguagens onde a `array` tem o tamanho fixado na declaração de variável  lista e array são muito distintos.